# Shortest path in a directed, unweighted graph with a selection criterion between multiple shortest paths?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, graph-theory, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

I am looking for the best way to solve this variation on the shortest-path problem:

I have a directed graph with unweighted edges. I need to be able to find the shortest path between any two nodes, if such a path exists. What makes this problem different than a regular shortest path problem is this: If multiple paths exist with shortest length, I need to be able to choose the path with the highest "authority".

Each node has a numerical authority and the path with the highest authority is simply the one with the highest sum of node authorities.

**In summary:**
I need the shortest path between a pair of nodes in a directed graph, but if there are multiple paths with the same, minimum length, I need to find the one with the highest path authority.

What is the best way to go about doing this? Is there some way to convert this into a weighted graph and then just use [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)? Is there some way to modify [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) to give me the set of shortest paths, which I can then iterate through to find the highest authority path?

Comment: It is not. Should I make that more clear in the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The edges are unweighted, so give eacn edge a weight of `1+auth(v,u)`. [auth is explained in the following line]

for each (v,u) set `auth(v,u) = max{authority} - authority(v)` (*) [this is true becuase if you use the edge leaving from `v`, you definetly visited it].

(*)`max{authority}` is the the highest authority in the graph.

normalize your "auth rank" so, `Sigma(auth(v,u),for each (v,u) in E) < 1` [by dividing, so the authority of edges will still be proportional to the original]

now, run [dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) on the graph with the new modified weights.

The shortest path found must be **shortest**, because the authority factor cannot overcome the distance factor, because it is to 'weak' [normalized to less then 1].

And it is the one with the **highest `authority`** [for vertices], since it is the one with the lowest `auth` [for edges], since it is minimal.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I am looking for. If you don't mind my asking for a few clarifications: in `auth(v,u)`, is `v` the source of an edge and `u` the destination? I feel like you are probably using standard graph notation, but unfortunately, I'm not totally familiar with it.

In `Sigma(auth(v,u),for each (v,u) in E)` is `E` the edge set? And I understand the goal of normalizing, but I don't understand how you are suggesting that I should (if you suggested a method at all).

Comment: (1) yes, v is the sorce, and u is the destination. (2) yes, E is the edges set. (3) One method to normalize is to **divide** `auth` for all edges by `max{authority} * (|E| + 1)`, this way you ensure there is no way the sum of auth for all edges is equal/greater then 1.

Comment: One more question if you don't mind: Calculating authority is a computationally intensive task, but I know the theoretical maximum authority, which is just the number of nodes. Could I use that for `max{authority}` or must it be the actual maximum authority?

Comment: @Genre: (1) it is not too expansive, it can be done with a single path on the edges set, and the bottleneck will eventually not be there. (2) However, yes - giving the theoretical max{authority} should be enough

Comment: Alright thanks. By the way, I meant that calculating the authority for a node is expensive, based on the way I have defined it. It isn't a static number.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing about Djikstra's algorithm forces you to use a scalar to represent the path cost.

A simple modification would be to use a pair instead of a single value, e.g. `(distance, authority)` to represent the cost of a path. The ordering would be `< distance`, then `> authority`, i.e., lower `distance` takes higher priority, then higher `authority` takes priority.